# javascript regexp allow only numbers issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text input field, where I am checking each click, so the user should enter only numbers. I need to do it with javascript.

I created this in my function:

```
 result = number.replace(/\D/g, '');return result;
```

I also tried  `result = number.replace(/[^0-9.\-]/g, '');return result;`

This is working, so it doesn't allow to enter anything except numbers, BUT if I press any letter twice (gg or aa,...) then one of the letters is showing in input field.

If I enter different letters (ab, gh,...), then it is ok, it doesn't allow any letter. It happens only if I press the same letter twice.

Not sure why it is happening, as the regexp should allow only numbers.

Comment: Try making `\D` as `\D+`

Comment: why don't you use the input attribute to allow only numbers?

Comment: `<input type="number" id="field" name="field" min="10" max="100">` will allow only numbers and with a range from 10 to 100

Comment: I can't do this, we have some rules for those inputs. I need to do it via aurelia decorator in backend

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi \D+ did not change anything

Comment: check this i think it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469357/html-text-input-allow-only-numeric-input

Answer (score 0):

You need to use lowercase d to matching digits instead of capital D. Also to match whole number use + sign after d like \d+.

here is regex cheat sheet : https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html

and you can use that link to simulate your regex : https://regexr.com/

Comment: if I use lowercase d+, then it replaces digits, I need to keep the digits. This number.replace(/\d/g, ''); will replace digits for nothing. So using capital D is ok in my case. The problem is just when I press 2 same letters

Comment: I've just tried that and its output is : 12344, **var res = "bbb123aa44".replace(new RegExp(/\D+/g), '');**

Comment: yes, because you use uppercase D, not lowercase as you suggested. With D it works, but I think I found the issue with duplicate letters. I tried to return parseFloat(result) and now it is working as expected.